# Why does std::min(std::initializer_list<T>) take arguments by value?

Tags: c++, c++11, min, std

Reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243578/stdinitializer-list-and-a-reference-parameter), I was surprised to find that `std::min(std::initializer_list<T>)` takes its arguments by value.

If you use `std::initializer_list` in the way implied by its name, i.e. as an initializer to some object, I understand that we don't care about copying its elements since they will be copied anyway to initialize the object. However, in this case here we most likely don't need any copy, so it would seem much more reasonable to take the arguments as `std::initializer_list<const T&>` if only it were possible.

What's the best practice for this situation? Should you not call the `initializer_list` version of `std::min` if you care about not making unnecessary copies, or is there some other trick to avoid the copy?

Comment: AFAIK, using a reference needs more CPU's cycles than passing a `int`'s copy, and needs more memory (at least on x86) than passing smaller variables.

Comment: True, but std::min is not restricted to int (or any numeric type). And for large objects it can be *very* important to forego the copy.

Comment: I think the reason is described in [N2722](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2722.pdd), though I'm reluctant to trust that performance comparison and the conclusion. There might be more discussion recorded somewhere.

Comment: Related: http://nd.home.xs4all.nl/dekkerware/issues/n2772_fix/draft_november_2009.htm

Comment: *"or is there some other trick to avoid the copy"* Well, you could pass an `initializer_list` of const pointers and use a custom comparator.

Comment: Or maybe use `std::reference_wrapper` as template argument ?

Comment: @dyp and germinolegrand: Both solutions have a problem when you want to mix temporary objects with non-temporary ones. You'd have to define the temporaries beforehand, which is clumsy. But all right, I asked whether it's possible and you showed me that it actually is, so I would mark your answers as accepted.

Comment: In fact, the best solution would be if there was an any_reference_wrapper which could bind both lvalue and rvalue references, but at the moment I don't know how to write such a thing.

Comment: @dyp Btw, in the n2772_fix it says that variadic templates are to be preferred over initializer_list. Why did the standard committee anyway decide to define std::min with an initializer_list rather than a variadic template?

Comment: I do not know, maybe there's something in the meeting minutes or some further discussion available. Otherwise, ask on [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-discussion). I'm not sure what the problem is you're describing wrt temporary objects. Though you may not directly take their address, it is possible to do so indirectly (or implement a `reference_wrapper` that accepts them). They live until the end of the full-expression, which is long enough for a `min`.

Comment: @gTcV I might be missing something but the note in 18.9/2 [support.initlist] explicitly says that "_Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements_". If I interpret this correctly, it would imply that the only things that get copied are the begin and end of the list (or begin and lenght or whatever). The [note in cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/?kw=initializer_list) and [in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) seem to say the same

Comment: @ComeRaczy: You are right.  But `std::min({thing1, function1(), function2(), thing2});` will make unnecessary copies of all four elements _into the initializer list_.

Comment: @dyp: link is broken, paper is now here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2722.pdf.

Comment: Somewhat related: the fact that ordinary before-initializer-lists-were-dreamt-up `std::min` takes its arguments by value has caused untold pain with odr-use of integral constant static member variables.

Comment: @gTcV : "*Why did the standard committee anyway decide to define std::min with an initializer_list rather than a variadic template?*" What would the return type be with a variadic template?

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as `std::initializer_list<const T&>`.  Initializer lists can only hold objects by value.

See [dcl.init.list]/5:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of N elements of type `const E`, where N is the number of elements in the initializer list.

There are no arrays of references, so there cannot be an `initializer_list` of references either.

My suggestion in this circumstance would be to write a replacement for `std::min` which takes a variadic template of forwarding references. This works (although I'm sure it can be improved):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T vmin( T arg1, Args&&... args )
{
    T *p[] = { &arg1, &args... };

    return **std::min_element( begin(p), end(p), 
            [](T *a, T *b) { return *a < *b; } );
}
```

[See it working](http://ideone.com/IfOL44) - using `min` or `mmin`, two extra copies are made (for `a` and `b`).

Answer (score 4):

To sum up the comments:

An `std::initializer_list` is supposed to be a lightweight proxy as described on  [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).
Therefore a copy of an initializer list should be very fast since the underlying elements are not copied:

**C++11 §18.9/2**

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E.`
>   [ *Note:*
>   A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for `initializer_list`.
>   `initializer_list` is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying elements.  — *end note* ]

Using a reference though would boil down to using a pointer and therefore an additional indirection.

The actual problem of `std::min` therefore is not that it takes the `initializer_list` by value, but rather, that the arguments to `initializer_list` have to be copied if they are computed at runtime. [1]
That the benchmark at [1] was broken as found out [later](http://nd.home.xs4all.nl/dekkerware/issues/n2772_fix/draft_november_2009.htm) is unfortunate.

```
auto min_var = std::min({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}); // fast
auto vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
min_var = std::min({vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], vec[3], vec[4]}); // slow
```

[1]: [N2722](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2722.pdf) p. 2

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood both the question _and_ the comments.  They complaint _is_ that the elements in the `initializer_list` are copied at runtime, rather than having an `initializer_list` of references.

Comment: Good point! I overlooked the "show 8 more comments" link, which resulted in an edit mayhem once I saw it. Though I would not say that I misunderstood the question. Because initializer list need not create copies when it is created.This depends on the situation.

Comment: Your "benchmark" appears to claim that copying an `int` is slow.  Shouldn't it be a vector of large expensive-to-copy objects?  (Ok, I see that the linked article does have exactly that, each is a `std::list` of millions of elements)

Comment: It is not a benchmark but rather an example to illustrate the issue and to keep the code small.